nginx always reports ssl errors
My application is doing a model like:
HAproxy -> nginx -> Django
With this model, my application works well, HAproxy load-balances requests to nginx, then nginx forwards requests to Django.
But in nginx's error log, it keeps generating an error:
2024/09/06 07:54:53 [crit] 9#9: *13 SSL_read() failed (SSL: error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading) while waiting for request, client: 10.84.112.171, server: 0.0.0.0:8005

where 10.84.112.171 is the HAproxy host's IP address, looks like HAproxy keeps invoke new connections to nginx and quickly close the connection.
Key part of HAproxy config is like:
frontend desperado
   bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/my_cert.pem
   mode tcp
   option forwardfor
   option http-server-close
   default_backend myservice

backend myservice
   mode tcp
   option forwardfor
   balance roundrobin
   server myservice001.mycompay.com:8005 check ssl verify none
   server myservice002.mycompay.com:8005 check ssl verify none

Kay part of ngnix config is like:
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/myservice/mycompany.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/myservice/mycompany.key;
    return 404;
}

server {
    listen      80;
    server_name myservice.maycompany.com;
    return 301 https://myservice.maycompany.com/;
}

server {
    listen      8005 ssl;
    server_name myservice001.maycompany.com;

    charset     utf-8;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/myservice.access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/myservice.error.log info;

    gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml text/javascript application/x-javascript;
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;

    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/myservice/mycompany.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/myservice/mycompany.key;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    location /static/ {
        root /build/git/myservice/myservice;     # your Django project's static files
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/var/run/myservice.sock;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}

I tried to search over Google but didn't find any useful info.

My bet is on haproxy's health checks. It should be regular entry in your logs.
There are many ways to change check behaviour. You may add http layer to it or tone it down to TCP/IP layer only by option tcp-check. Right now it just opens SSL/TLS connection and when successfully negotiated, closes it, which may confuse nginx, because it expected more.
